# Do Ruby symbols exist because strings are mutable and not interned?

Tags: ruby

I've been with Ruby for about a year now and have a language question: are symbols necessary because Ruby strings are mutable and not interned?

In, say, Java, strings are immutable and interned.  So "foo" is always equal to "foo" in value and reference and its value cannot change.  In Ruby, strings are mutable and not interned, so `"a".object_id == "a".object_id` will be false.

If Ruby had implemented strings like Java, symbols wouldn't be necessary, right?

Comment: Sidenote: As of 2.3 you can supply a flag for immutable String Literals `RUBYOPT=--enable-frozen-string-literals` which will make all literal strings (e.g. "This") frozen and immutable. This changes is currently planned to be default for Ruby 3.0 but it does not dispose of symbols. Symbols have their own place in ruby beyond "string" functionality, take `Symbol#to_proc` for example, which is extremely popular syntax how would one deal with this as a string?

Comment: This comment by @engineersmnky is the best answer here so far and I believe it should be converted into an answer. `Symbol#to_proc` is worth pretty much everything in Ruby.

Comment: @mudasobwa adapted to an answer with a bit more context

Answer (score 7):

As of Ruby 2.3 immutable `String`s have been implemented optionally via the `RUBYOPT` flag `--enable-frozen-string-literals`
i.e.

```
RUBYOPT=--enable-frozen-string-literals ruby /some/file
```

This will cause all `String` literals (strings created using `""`, `%q{}`, `%Q{}`, or "#{}" styles) to become immutable. This feature is currently being considered as default for Ruby 3.0. [Follow along with Feature#11473](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/11473). This feature is also available on a file level rather than a global level as a "magic comment"

```
# frozen_string_literal: true
```

This will have the same impact as the `RUBYOPT` version but will apply only to the specific file. (one other way is to interact with the VM directly `RubyVM::InstructionSequence.compile_option = {frozen_string_literal: true}`)

Since this is optional obviously it can be turned on and off and will still be an option in 3.0 just defaulting to on instead of off. Mutable `String`s can still be created using `String.new` and Immutable `String`s can be `dup`ed to make their `dup` counter part mutable. (**Please Note above: interpolation `"#{}"` creates a new Immutable string as well because of `""`**)

All that being said it does not replace the need for `Symbols` in ruby. First of all the underlying `C` that powers ruby leverages `Symbols` heavily via `rb_itern` to handle references for things like method definitions (These have been titled *"Immortal Symbols"* and will never be GCed).

Additionally `Symbols` like all things in ruby are their own `Object` and have their own useful sets of functionality. Take `Symbol#to_proc` for example. This originated as a monkey patch solution for syntactical ease and was consumed into core in 1.8.7. This style is highly encouraged and regularly leveraged by the ruby community as a whole. Please advise how you would suggest having degradation of this feature work with a `String` instead of a `Symbol`.

While `Symbols` used to be considered somewhat "dangerous" (for lack of a better word) due to their internment and memory consumption in combination with the dynamics of ruby. As of Ruby 2.2 most `Symbols` (see above)  can be garbage collected i.e. symbols created inside of ruby  through `String` internment (`#intern`, `#to_sym`, etc.). (These have been coined *"Mortal Symbols"*)

Minor caveats include things like

```
 define_method(param[:meth].to_sym) {}
```

This seems like since it is calling `to_sym` that it should be a *"Mortal Symbol"* but since `define_method` calls `rb_intern` to keep the method reference it actually will create an *"Immortal Symbol"*

Hopefully this run down helps explain the necessity of `Symbol` in ruby not only from a developer standpoint but also the heavy usage as part of the `C` internals of ruby's implementation.

Comment: Thank you for putting your time/effort in this, this is a great answer.

Answer (score 2):

Pretty much, yes. My understanding is that the compiler keeps a table of symbols, which can grow dynamically. This is why you must never accept user-input and convert it unchecked into symbols, because you can create what's called a **symbol overflow attack**.

I believe the symbol overflow vulnerability was patched in Ruby 2.2.

see [Getting warning : Denial of Service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24066556/getting-warning-denial-of-service)

Comment: i never knew about symbol overflow attacks! how interesting!

Comment: With a modern Ruby, this is not as much a problem as is used to be (that is, creating a symbol is now as expensive as any other object). Earlier versions of Ruby have kept existing Symbols in memory indefinitely. Since Ruby 2.2 however, symbols will also be garbage collected, similar to (almost) any other object.

Comment: @eiko -- run Breakman (https://github.com/presidentbeef/brakeman) on your Rails app — you'll learn a bunch of things! As Holger Just said this applies only to Ruby version < 2.2

Answer (score 2):

Java-like strings would replace the functionality of symbols, so in that sense you are correct. However, I don't think Matz would be happy with a language which only has immutable and interned strings.

With strings and symbols, Ruby offers the best of both worlds. Symbols provide memory-efficiency for read-only strings like hash keys, whereas mutable strings are memory-efficient for string operations like concatenation.

So maybe "if Ruby had implemented strings like Java" isn't the right train of thought. Ruby *did* implement strings like Java. And they're called "symbols." Then Ruby implemented a second type of string, which it calls a "string." The naming is purely aesthetic, but I think it makes sense.

Comment: There is also a middle ground: frozen Strings. With a modern Ruby, frozen string literals are even handled almost the same as Symbols (e.g. they also get interned, similar to as symbols) and share the same performance advantages. Because of that, there is a growing number of people who advocate getting rid of the concept of Symbols in Ruby altogether in favour of frozen strings. You are right however in that the distinction between (generally mutable) Strings and immutable interned Symbols used to be much more prominent.

Comment: @HolgerJust “there is a growing number of people who advocate getting rid of the concept of Symbols in Ruby altogether in favour of frozen strings”—what?! That is a nonsense, since getting rid of `Symbol`s will ruin approximately 100% of existing code (that in turn everywhere relies on `Symbol#to_proc` behaviour in code like `[1,2,3].reduce(:+)`.)

Comment: Well, it's still a discussion and is quite controversial at that... One proposal would be to make symbols in code just syntactic sugar for frozen strings. And realistically, most of the advantages of Symbols are already implemented for frozen strings already, including usage in Hash keys, literal creation, ... As for `Symbol#to_proc`: nothing prevents anyone from implementing `String#to_proc` the same way as it's done for Symbols today.

Comment: @mudasobwa And it's even just one line of code :) `String.class_eval { define_method("to_proc") { s = self; proc{ |o, arg| o.public_send(s, arg) } } }` allows you to run `[1,2,3].reduce(&"+")` and get the same result as `[1,2,3].reduce(:+)`.

Comment: @HolgerJust that is just a simple example of useful `Symbol` syntax sugar. How about you take a look at `rb_intern()` in the `C` code and how that might impact the loss of `Symbol` internment

Comment: What I originally wanted to say was: the differences between Symbols and frozen Strings are getting smaller on every new version of Ruby, including its internment handling. There is (or was) a discussion about how Symbols and Strings can be unified but it's not something that (to my knowledge) is actively pursued as an actual goal in Ruby core development right now. There are still major areas in Ruby where the unification is not (yet) useful or possible but we are getting nearer to that constantly.

Answer (score 2):

> I've been with Ruby for about a year now and have a language question: are symbols necessary because Ruby strings are mutable and not interned?

No.

`Symbol` and `String` are simply two different data types. `String` is for text, `Symbol` is for labels.

> In, say, Java, strings are immutable and interned.

No, they are not. They are immutable and sometimes interned, sometimes not. If `String`s were interned, then why is there a method [`java.lang.String.intern()`](http://download.java.net/java/jdk9/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#intern--) which interns a `String`? `String`s in Java are only interned if

- you call `java.lang.String.intern()` or
- the `String` is the result of a `String` literal expression or
- the `String` is the result of `String`-typed constant value expression

Otherwise, they are not.

> So "foo" is always equal to "foo" in value and reference and its value cannot change.

Again, this is not true:

```java
class Test {
  public static void main(String... args) {
    System.out.println("foo".equals(args[0]));
    System.out.println("foo" == args[0]);
  }
}
```

Call it with

```sh
java Test foo
# true
# false
```

> In Ruby, strings are mutable and not interned, so `"a".object_id == "a".object_id` will be false.

In modern Ruby, that is not necessarily true either:

```
#frozen_string_literal: true
"a".object_id == "a".object_id
#=> true
```

> If Ruby had implemented strings like Java, symbols wouldn't be necessary, right?

No. Like I said, they are different types for different use cases.

Take a look at [Scala](http://scala-lang.org/), for example, which implements "strings like Java" (in fact, on the JVM implementation of Scala, [*there is no* `String`](http://scala-lang.org/api/current/?search=String), Scala `String` simply *is* `java.lang.String`). Yet, it also has a [`Symbol`](http://scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/Symbol.html) class.

Likewise, [Clojure](http://clojure.org/) has not one but *two* datatypes like Ruby's `Symbol`: [keywords](https://clojure.org/reference/data_structures#Keywords) are exactly equivalent to Ruby's `Symbol`s, they evaluate to themselves and stand only for themselves. [Symbols](https://clojure.org/reference/data_structures#Symbols) OTOH *may* stand for something else.

[Erlang](http://erlang.org/) has [immutable strings](http://erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/data_types.html#id70947) and [*atoms*](http://erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/data_types.html#id70888), which are like Clojure/Lisp symbols.

[ECMAScript](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/) has [immutable strings](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-string-objects) and recently added a [`Symbol`](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-symbol-objects) datatype. They are not 100% equivalent to Ruby `Symbol`s, though, since they have an additional guarantee: not only do they evaluate only to themselves and stand only for themselves, but they are also unforgeable (meaning it is impossible to create a `Symbol` which is equal to another `Symbol`).

Note that Ruby is moving away from mutable strings:

- [Ruby 2.1](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/9042) optimizes the pattern `'literal string'.freeze` to return a frozen string from a global string pool.
- [Ruby 2.3](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/11473) introduces the `# frozen_string_literal: true` pragma and `--enable=frozen-string-literal` feature toggle switch to make all string literals frozen (and pooled) by default on a per-script (pragma) or per-process (feature toggle) basis.
- Ruby 3 will switch the default for both of those to `true`, so that you have to explicitly say `# frozen_string_literal: false` or `--disable=frozen-string-literal` in order to get the current behavior.
- Some later version will remove support for mutable strings altogether.